# How to switch to older version in React?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-dom

I am currently using React@17.2.1. I have done some work using this version of React but I need to switch to older version of react@16.0.0. Is their anyway to switch to this version?

Here are my dependencies:

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-popper": "^1.3.7",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-scripts": "1.1.4",
"redux": "^3.7.2"
"react-redux": "7.2.2"
```